# Voltage regulation using TL494

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator, power-electronics, tl494

I want to use TL494 IC for voltage regulation. For this, I am giving a 2.5 V reference to the inverting pin of the error amplifier and wants to vary a voltage from 0- 5V at the non inverting terminal through potentiometer. And having a gain of 100 through the resistance of 51 kohm and 510 ohm. But when I'm varying the voltage at pin1 that is non inverting terminal, I'm obtaining a pulse signal only for a second and then it's becoming a constant voltage at the output. What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: The TI datasheet has a test circuit. Try that. If it doesn’t work, then maybe you have a dud chip or some more fundamental problem like a broken wire.

Comment: Diagram at a minimum must be properly oriented.